# ComboBox contains the same data

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, combobox

I added the data from the XML to the ComboBox, but I have some duplicate data.
How can I fix this?

I tried the following:

```
var itemTar = from key in xmlDocument.Descendants("donem")
                        select key.Value;
        //comboBox2.DataSource = itemTar.ToList();
        if (comboBox2.Contains(itemTar.ToString()))
        {

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < comboBox2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < comboBox2.Items.Count; j++)
            {
                if (comboBox2.Items[i] == comboBox2.Items[j])
                {
                    comboBox2.Items.Remove(comboBox2.Items[j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
```

this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?>
<all>
<s_section id="119342">
<ad>a tic.</ad>
<donem id="10890686" dt="31/12/2017" ds="01/01/2017" s="1">01/01/2017 - 
31/12/2017</donem>
</s_section>
<s_section id="4248622">
<ad>DENEME</ad>
<donem id="9851537" dt="31/12/2017" ds="01/01/2017" s="1">01/01/2017 -             
31/12/2017</donem>
</s_section>
<s_section id="4678788">
<ad>DENETİM16</ad>
<donem id="10711887" dt="31/12/2017" ds="01/01/2017" s="1">01/01/2017 - 
31/12/2017</donem>
<donem id="10711886" dt="31/12/2016" ds="01/01/2016" s="1">01/01/2016 - 
31/12/2016</donem>
</s_section>
```

Comment: You need to clear the items from duplicates before setting the combobox datasource. You need distinct in that query. But could you show a sample of your xml input text?

Comment: I added the xml file.

Comment: The data that you shared is representing a list of `s_section` objects having these properties `s_section: {id, ad, donem: {id, dt, ds, s, text} }`. What you are going to show in the `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to remove duplicate strings, all you need is a call to Distinct and then set the DataSource of your combobox.

```
var itemTar = (from key in xmlDocument.Descendants("donem")
                    select key.Value).Distinct().ToList();
comboBox2.DataSource = itemTar;
```